# flex compilation issue, linking to libfl fails

Tags: c++, linker, flex-lexer

I am trying to compile the minimal example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285818/problem-with-using-a-generated-file-from-flex).

I keep getting an error related to an undefined reference to yywrap().
The [manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/I-get-an-error-about-undefined-yywrap_0028_0029_002e.html) suggests to:

- define my own `yywrap()` function, or
- use the `noyywrap`option, or
- link to `libfl.so`

In my case, linking to `libfl` fails. The two other options yield a successful compilation.

---

The code in question:

**test.ll**

```
%option c++

%%

%%
```

**test.c**

```
int main()
{
    return 42;
}
```

compile these files with:

```
flex test.ll
g++ -c lex.yy.cc 
g++ -o test test.c lex.yy.o -lfl
```

Then, after running `./test`, `echo $?` should return 42.

In my case, the last step of the compilation fails, and I get:

```
lex.yy.o:(.rodata._ZTV11yyFlexLexer[_ZTV11yyFlexLexer]+0x68): undefined reference to `yyFlexLexer::yywrap()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib/libfl.so: undefined reference to `yylex'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `option c++`, yywrap must be defined as part of yyFlexLexer class: `int yyFlexLexer::yywrap();`. Also don't forget that C++ mangles names. If you really want to call yywrap version defined in libfl, you may use following code. It defines yywrap as part of class as expected by code generated by flex, and this member function calls original yywrap function provided by libfl. But actually I do not see any reason why you may want to use original yywrap function: either use option noyywrap if you don't need any magic, or implement yywrap on your own with all required magic.

```
%option c++ 

%%

%%

extern "C" {
  int yywrap();
}

int yyFlexLexer::yywrap() {
  return ::yywrap();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for the answer. My original question was inspired by a problem I had with an open source code, that failed to compile on my system. After some testing I decided to build a minimal working example to test, if flex is the source of my problem. With my minimal example I noticed that linking to libfl failed, that made me curious.

Comment: Now g++ is complaining about an undefined reference to yylex

Answer (score 0):

I also got same errors when I was cross compiling OpenFOAM for xeonphi. OpenFOAM depends on flex library so I need to cross compile it for Xepnphi. So when I tried cross compile flex for xeonphi, it did not show any errors while cross compiling flex. But when I am compiling OpenFOAM I got error "libfl.so: undefined reference to `yylex". So I looked into libfl.a and linfl.so to find if there is definition exists. I could not find definition of yylex in libfl.a and libfl.so(objdump --syms libfl.a showed UND for yylex function). If I check objdump --syms yylex.o, it showed yylex is defined in it(It showed text option). I am wondering whether I compiled flex correctly or not. Please let me know what can be done